# Удалить пробелы в начале выбранной опции в селекте Chosen

Tags: jquery, chosen

Всем привет!
Очень надеюсь на помощь знатоков.

На проекте используется плагин Chosen Select.

Есть селект. Опции внутри него имитируют древовидную структура за счет добавленных пробелов

```
&nbsp;
```

При выборе определенной опции, в контейнере a.chosen-single результат должен отображаться без пробелов. 
Я пробовала разобраться сама, но пока что новичок, не понимаю что делаю не так.

Спасибо заранее за помощь.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".chosen-select").chosen();
  $('.chosen-single').find('span').each(function() {
    $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/&nbsp;/gi, ''));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.4.2/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.4.2/chosen.min.css">

<div>
  <select data-placeholder="Choose a Country..." class="chosen-select" style="width:350px;" tabindex="4">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="Any">[Any]</option>
    <option value="United States">&nbsp;United States</option>
    <option value="United Kingdom">&nbsp;&nbsp;United Kingdom</option>
    <option value="Afghanistan">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Afghanistan</option>
    <option value="Aland Islands">&nbsp;Aland Islands</option>
    <option value="Albania">&nbsp;&nbsp;Albania</option>
    <option value="Algeria">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Algeria</option>
    <option value="American Samoa">American Samoa</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kaintz/3roq54bf/7/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Просто Вы ищете и удаляете пробелы только при первом запуске, а надо при каждом изменении селекта:

```
$(document).ready(function(){  

   $(".chosen-select").chosen();

  $(".chosen-select").change(function(){
    $('.chosen-single').find('span').html(function (i, html) {
      return html.replace(/&nbsp;/g, '');
    });
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте этот скрипт:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".chosen-select").chosen().change(function() {
    $('.chosen-single').find('span').html($(this).val());
  });
});
```

Просто вставил val в span на событие change.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
    $(".chosen-select").chosen();
    $(".chosen-select").on("change", function() {
        let span = $(".chosen-single span");
        span.text(span.text().trim());
    });
});
```